# colorbox option to display instance variable

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I was implementing the colorbox modal for my web application. I am stuck in displaying an instance variable in my colorbox.

I could not find an option in the colorbox website to do such a thing.

This is my code.

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url:'/leave', 
async: false,
data:{ foo1:currentCellText 
}, 
success:function(data){
$.colorbox({html: "<%= @cook%>",  width:"25%",height:"200px"});
},
error:function(data){
alert("Failure");
}
});
```

My instance variable @cook has an array. How can I display the array contents in colorbox?

Hope someone can help me out.

Regards,
Nikhil

Comment: Could you share some code?

Comment: Plz remember this place helps in code where you got stuck, so pasting that piece of code is rquired, so that one can give solution for your query.

Comment: Sorry Guys. Ill put up my code in the next comment

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){var Text; $(".inline").click(function(e) { Text = $(this).text(); $.ajax({ type: 'GET', url:'/leave', async: false, data:{ foo1:Text }, success:function(data){ $.colorbox({html: "<%= @cook%>", width:"25%",height:"200px"}); }, error:function(data){ alert("Failure"); } }); }); });

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague....

*If you want to display the complete array in one instance of the plugin*, consider using ColorBox to open its content in an iFrame. That way, inside the frame you'll have a complete DOM environment (as a child to the calling window) in which to do anything you need to.

In side of that environment you'll need to work out how to extract the individual array elements and display them.

*If you want to display each array element in its own ColorBox*, that's a different story. For that you'll need to work out how to apply the plugin to each array element and a method by which the lightbox is triggered.

Comment: Hello Kevin. I tried iframe after you suggested. I am now getting an error. "Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/undefined"

Try running rake routes for more information on available routes." I googled it but I cudnt understand where I am going wrong. Can you point out where I am wrong

Comment: I'm not a RoR expert, but it looks like you are making an Ajax GET with a URL string that isn't defined to the server. Try putting some console.log statements in the Success and Failure callbacks so you can see exactly what you are GETting to the backend. Maybe that will help...

Comment: Hello Kevin, I was rendering it wrong. That was the main reason. I had to use "respond_to". It worked for me. Thank you all for your suggestions and time.